# component object modelling using python

Tags: python-2.7, excel, com, vba

I'm trying to use COM through python to use STAAD.Pro. Using the following code in excel VBA gives perfectly fine results.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Set Obj = GetObject(, "StaadPro.OpenSTAAD")
Dim x3 As Long
Dim x4 As Double

x3 = 9
x4 = 0

Obj.Output.GetMemberSteelDesignRatio x3, x4
Cells(1, 1) = Obj.GetProcessId
Cells(1, 2) = x4

End Sub
```

But the same thing when I'm trying to implement in Python I'm getting error as "Bool Object is not callable"

```
>>> import win32com.client
>>> obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("StaadPro.OpenSTAAD")
>>> obj.GetProcessId
10260
>>> x3 = 9
>>> x4 = 0.0
>>> obj.Output.GetMemberSteelDesignRatio(x3, x4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
>>> obj.Output.GetMemberSteelDesignRatio(long(x3), float(x4))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
>>>
```

Help.

Comment: For one, I would inspect `obj`. In particular, look at what `obj.GetMemberSteelDesignRatio` is.

Comment: obj.Output.GetMemberSteelDesignRatio takes an integer and 'Pointer Real 8' type arguments. What is 'Ponter Real 8' type argument? I tried passing a pointer as "obj.Output.GetMemberSteelDesignRatio(int(x3), *x4)" but got an error saying "bool object argument after * must be an iterable, not int"